# WCELOAD is not installing my CAB file

Tags: windows-mobile

We are trying to install a cab file on Windows Mobile device. The WCELOAD.exe is present on the device on RAM because I am able to tap on the cab and install it, but I do not see it in the windows folder. I have tried to see the hidden file, by checking "Show all files". However we will need to do this for over 1000 devices and need to be able to do it programatically. Can someone please recommend how can I launch wceload in ROM from commandline or move it to Windows Folder?

I need to be able to install a cab file from command line. I tried \Windows\Wceload.exe /silent xyz.cab but it did not work. I have also tried \Windows\wceload.exe xyz.cab and it did not work. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I do not see any error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain what you're asking here.  `wceload.exe` is present in *every* Windows Mobile device.  Period.  Yes, it's a hidden file, and you can't see it in Explorer (remote file viewer will show it), but why, exactly, do you need to "see" it?  It is guaranteed to be there. and cannot be deleted.

What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve here? I suspect maybe you're getting an error when attempting to run a CAB file, but your question is far from clear.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you're having problem getting wceload to install your CAB, notactually finding the app.  That's a different issue.

Things to note:

1. Windows CE has no notion of a "current directory" so you *must* provide a fully qualified path to both wceload *and your CAB file*:

   ```
   Process.Start("\\windows\\wceload.exe", "\\Folder\\myapp.cab");
   ```
2. The cab file path is a single parameter to wceload.  That means that if it has a space in the path, you have to delimit it, otherwise it just looks for everything up to the space, and will give an ambiguous error.

   ```
   Process.Start("\\windows\\wceload.exe", "'\\Storage Card\\myapp.cab'"); // note the single quotes in there
   ```

Comment: I am sure wceload.exe is present. But I need to be able to install a cab file from command line. I tried \\Windows\Wceload.exe /silent xyz.cab but it did not work. I have also tried \\Windows\wceload.exe xyz.cab I cannot see the wceload.exe in the Windows folder. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I do not see any error messages.

Comment: I have a middleware application to which I pass the command and arguments through a user interface. I am passing the command as Windows\WCELOAD.exe and Arguments as "\Storage Card\Installs\ABC\xyz.cab". No errors are being recorded but still the xyz.cab is not installed. My guess is, it is unable to locate wceload.exe.

Answer (score 2):

First check if the cab file can be installed the manaual way:

- open file explorer on the device
- locate the cab file in file explorer
- tap on the cab file once within the device's file explorer

If there is any error with the cab you will see it.

If there is no error message, check if your cab is installed. If it seems to be not installed you have to check the cab and what it tries to install (see OCP WinCE CabManager).

Possible cab install problems:

- A cab file cannot be installed if it tries to replace an open file
- you cannot install unsigned cab files and apps on secured devices
- installation architecture must match the device's one

If the cab file can be installed just follow ctacke's advise. If you cannot use CreateProcess, you can also test command line installation using itsutils (see xda-developers.com wiki).For example, if the cab file is "\My Documents\mycabfile.cab" and you have an activesync connection, you can run remotely:

prun "\windows\wceload.exe" "\My Documents\mycabfile.cab"

As you see, first try the normal way. If this runs OK you may add optional arguments as the "/silent" option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158700.aspx):

prun "\windows\wceload.exe" /silent "\My Documents\mycabfile.cab"

Always check manual install before attempting automated install.